# Completely two different tabs with different routes in Angular Ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I was trying to get two different completely tabs menus on Angular Ionic app. I have already tabs on the bottom of my app.

1st menu tabs

**Dashboard - Search - Inbox - Profile**

I need to create 2nd menu tabs:

**Dashboard - Games - Chat - Contact**

I want to have the same Dashboard in both cases.

In my Tabs Routing module :

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tabs',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        loadChildren: () => import('../search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'inbox',
        loadChildren: () => import('../inbox/inbox.module').then(m => m.InboxPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: () => import('../profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ContactPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/about',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/about',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Tabs html page

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="about">
      <ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Dashboard</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    
    <ion-tab-button tab="tabs">
      <ion-icon name="play-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Search</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tabs">
      <ion-icon name="albums"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Index</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="blog">
      <ion-icon name="albums-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

I have difficulties to define the routing for the second type of tabs.

Is it possible to have two completely different tabs in Angular? If yes, I would really appreciate if you could help me with Routing or any tips very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to have a url which is effectively two url's combined? one for the first tab and one for the 2nd tab?

Comment: What about using child routes , you can make dashboard route as parent and define all other child and make some conditions

Comment: Rebai Ahmed thanks for respond, I was thinking about actually only I have tabs already as a parent and dashboard is a child. But I have another problem with styling because the second type of tabs should have different style also.